# latex table border dont appear / to big / to small

Tags: tables

still working on that table. Here's my new question reguarding the table borders:

It appears, that i do something wrong setting boarders. Here is my code, and a screenshot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} % Used for the vertical cells
\usepackage{rotating} % Used for the vertical cells

\usepackage{xcolor} % Used for cell-colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % Used for cell-colors

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% Used to set the pdf margins manually
\newgeometry{left=2cm,bottom=0.1cm}

\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{F2F2F2} % Define grey for the cells
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FF0000} % Define red for testing

\begin{document}
\scriptsize % Use a small font size

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0,6cm}|}

\cline{10-17}

\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*2+2\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\cellcolor{grey}Work to retired ratio} & \multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*4+1\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{Health care sizing (per thousand)} & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*2+1\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\cellcolor{grey}Inverse dependency ratio}\\\cline{3-9}

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{grey}Population (mio.)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Workforce (1000)}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{grey}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Physicians by} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Nurses by} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{grey}Old agers by}\\\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \begin{sideways}\cellcolor{grey}\parbox{4cm}{Overall}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\cellcolor{grey}\parbox{4cm}{Young age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\cellcolor{grey}\parbox{4cm}{Working age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\cellcolor{grey}\parbox{4cm}{Old age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Overall}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Physicians (Proj: 2025)}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Nurses (Proj: 2030)}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{\cellcolor{grey}Working age by Old age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{\cellcolor{grey}Work force by Old age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Workforce}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Working age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Workforce}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Working age}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{\cellcolor{grey}1 physicians}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{\cellcolor{grey}1 nurse}\end{sideways}\\\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l}{USA} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\cellcolor{grey}} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{grey}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor{grey}}\\\hline

1990/1 & & 248,6 & 71,3 & 146,1 & 31,2 & 127.500 & 615,4 & 1491,6 & 4,68 & 4,09 & 4,83 & 4,21 & 11,70 & 10,21 & 50,7 & 20,9\\\hline

1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On 1 the Top border of Population is not visible although i did used `\\\cline{3-9}\cline{12-17}` on that line.

In 2 both borders are pushed a bit to the right for no reason i can see.

And in 3 again the top borders are not visible despite using `\cline{10-17}` on that line. What did i do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in the `colortbl` documentation you can not use `\cline` with `colortbl` as `\cline` rules take up no vertical space so are over-printed by the coloured panels.
You can use `\hhline` from the `hhline` package, which has a different syntax.

As mentioned last time the vertical rules are at the *right* edge of the column so use

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{..}&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{..}&
```

not

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{..}&
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{..}&
```

Otherwise you get duplicated, mis-aligned vertical rules. Only the first cell in a row should have a rule on the left.

3 is `\cline` again.

Also `rotating` package is useful for its `sidewaystable` environment but for rotating text it just really keeps `sideways` for compatibility with the LaTeX2.09 package from last century, it uses the `graphicx` package and you can simply use that and `\rotatebox{90}{..}` directly.

You also had the calculation of the spanning width incorrect. If you span 4 columns, you have to account for 3 (= 4-1) missing rules and the space wither side of them =6\tabcolsep (6=2*(4-1))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} % Used for the vertical cells
\usepackage{graphicx} % Used for the vertical cells
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Used for cell-colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % Used for cell-colors

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% Used to set the pdf margins manually
\newgeometry{left=2cm,bottom=0.1cm}

\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{F2F2F2} % Define grey for the cells
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FF0000} % Define red for testing

\begin{document}
\scriptsize % Use a small font size

\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{p{0.6cm}|}}

\hhline{*9{~}*8-}

\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*2+1\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\cellcolor{grey}\centering Work to retired ratio}&
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*4+3\arrayrulewidth+6\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\centering Health care sizing\\ (per thousand)}&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*2+1\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\cellcolor{grey}\centering Inverse dependency ratio}\\
\hhline{~~------->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&
 \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{grey}Population (mio.)}&
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Workforce (1000)}&
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{grey}}&
 \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Physicians by}&
 \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nurses by}&
 \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor{grey}Old agers by}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Overall}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Young age}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Working age}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Old age}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Overall}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Physicians (Proj: 2025)}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Nurses (Proj: 2030)}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Working age by Old age\ }&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}Work force by Old age\ }&
 \rotatebox{90}{Workforce}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Working age}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Workforce}&
 \rotatebox{90}{Working age}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}1 physicians}&
 \rotatebox{90}{\cellcolor{grey}1 nurse}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{USA}&
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\cellcolor{grey}}&
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{}&
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{grey}}&
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{}&
 \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor{grey}}\\\hline

1990/1&& 248,6& 71,3& 146,1& 31,2& 127.500& 615,4& 1491,6& 4,68& 4,09& 4,83& 4,21& 11,70& 10,21& 50,7& 20,9\\\hline

1& 2& 3 \\\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that looks almost perfect. Thank you very much! Just one question so i understand that correctly: I found an explanation of hhline telling me what *8(~) and +9(-) stands for, but i couldnt find what \hhline{~~------->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}} does mean...

Comment: @Shiuyin It's a `colortbl` extension to `\hhline` the `>` syntax mimics the `>` syntax in array preambles and allows declarations that affect the rules (probably only color makes sense) it is a global colour switch so you have to explicitly set it back to black. `texdoc colortbl` has full info (see Richard of York example:-)

Comment: @ Davin Carlisle: So then \hhline{~~>{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}--->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{grey}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}} means: 2 blanks followed by 4 grey's, followed by 3 blacks, followed by 2 greys, followed by 4 blacks, followed by 2 greys, followed by black for the next border color? Doesn't work...

Comment: @Shiuyin doesn't work in what way? see the image I posted (which isn't full line) worked for me, sometimes you have to zoom in a bit, depends on the pdf viewer

Comment: @Shiuyin oh in your comment above you have a trailing `>` you can't do that it is an operator that applies to the following segment